# MemSQL: I got error when inserting data with spark to the DB

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, import, singlestore

The Error:

Could not query S3: An error occurred (400) when calling the HeadObject operation: Bad Request

What is the cause of this error?

thanks!

Comment: Please share some context, such as the code executed and some information about your cluster. Thanks

Comment: Solved. It was a permission problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. It was a permission problem.